# Validating successful RDP connection through command line

Tags: validation, command-line, rdp

I have been looking for a snippet of code that would allow you to actually connect to RDP and validate that it worked, rather than just confirming that a port is listening on a remote host. This would confirm that if there was an error during TCP handshake that RDP was actually not able to begin. Any suggestions, as this function is not an output per se?

I already have simple code that can be scheduled to start the RDP session, but how do you check if a RDP session was allowed (keeping in mind that if you do not have admin rights to the remote machine you cannot validate by the "Query Session /server:servername" command)?

Answer (score 0):

You can subscribe to the [OnLoginComplete event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa382686%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) exposed by the Remote Desktop ActiveX control to get this information. Of course, to do this, you'd need to write your own app that uses the ActiveX control rather than launching mstsc.